# How to perform different operations on matrix using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

There is segmentation fault in `case 5` of this program(transpose) this segmentation fault occurs only when the input row is greater than that of the input column. Hopefully this is due to the reason I have not allocated the memory accordingly.

```
b= (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
```

And if I am doing it accordingly like this:

```
b= (int**)malloc(c*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
```

there still is seg. fault and this time it is not producing correct output for matrix of any order.

***Here is my full code :***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int** inputmatrix(int **a,int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("\n Input the Elements of the Matrix :");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
void showmatrix(int** a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("  %d",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int** add(int **a, int **b, int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
int** multiplication(int** a, int **b, int r1, int c1, int c2)
{
    int **c,i,j,k;
    c = (int**)malloc(r1*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
    {
        c[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for(k=0; k<c1; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int minval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, min;
    min = a[r][0];
    for(i=0; i<c; ++i)
    {
        if(a[r][i]<min)
        {
            min = a[r][i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int maxval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, max;
    max = a[0][c];
    for(i=0; i<r; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i][c] > max )
        {
            max = a[i][c];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void saddlepoint(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, rpos, cpos, flag = 0,sp;
    for(i=0; i<r; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; ++j)
        {
            if(a[i][j] == minval(a, i, c) && a[i][j] == maxval(a, r, j))
            {
                sp = a[i][j];
                flag = 1;
                rpos = i;
                cpos = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        printf("\n The Saddle point of the Matrix is found at position (%d,%d) value is %d ", rpos, cpos,sp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n There is no saddle point in the Matrix ");
    }
}

int magicsquare(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, row_sum, col_sum, d1, d2, flag = 0;
    if(r==c)
    {
        for(i =0 ;i<r; i++)         // for digonals
         {
            d1 = d1 + a[i][i];
            d2 = d2 + a[i][r-i-1];
        }
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            row_sum = 0;
            for(j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                row_sum = row_sum + a[i][j];
            }
            if(row_sum == d1)
                flag = 1;
            else
                break;
        }
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            col_sum = 0;
            for(j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                col_sum = col_sum + a[j][i];
            }
            if(col_sum == d1)
                flag =1;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n This Matrix is not a Magic Square ");
    }
    return flag;
}

int** transpose(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, **b;
    b= (int**)malloc(c*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i =0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int **a, **b,r1,c1,r2,c2, i,j,ch,f;
    int **c;
    printf("\n enter your choice : \n1.Addition \n2.Multiplication \n3.Saddle Point \n4. Magic Square \n5.Transpose\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    printf("\n enter the oder of matrix A :");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
                printf("\n enter the oder of matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
                if(r1==r2 && c1==c2)
                {
                    b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                    a = add(a,b,r1,c1);
                    printf("\n the result of the addition of matrices is :");
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0;j<c1; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n these matrices can't be added ");
                }
                break;
        case 2 :
                printf("\n Enter the Order of Matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
                b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                if(c1 == r2)
                {
                    c = multiplication(a, b, r1, c1, r2);
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n Sorry, These Matrices Can't be Multiplied ");
                }
                break;
        case 3 :
                printf("\n The Matrix you Entered is :");
                for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
                    {
                        printf("  %d",a[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                saddlepoint(a,r1,c1);
                break;
        case 4 :
                printf("\n The Matrix you Entered is :");
                for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
                    {
                        printf("  %d",a[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                int f =  magicsquare(a, r1, c1);
                if(f==1)
                    printf("\n This Matrix is a Magic Square ");
                else
                    printf("\n This Matrix is not a Magic Square ");
                break;
        case 5 :
                printf("\n The Matrix you enter is :");
                showmatrix(a,r1,c1);
                b = transpose(a,r1,c1);
                printf("\n the transpose of the entered matrix is :");
                for(i=0; i<c1; i++)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    for(j=0; j<r1; j++)
                    {
                        printf("  %d",b[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                break;

        default : printf("\n Sorry, This is a Wrong Choice ");
            }
    return 0;
}
```

***A few Output cases are also below:***

**case 1:**

```
enter your choice : 
1.Addition 
2.Multiplication 
3.Saddle Point 
4. Magic Square 
5.Transpose
5

enter the oder of matrix A :3
2

Input the Elements of the Matrix :1
2
3
4
5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**case 2:**

```
enter your choice:
1.Addition 
2.Multiplication 
3.Saddle Point
4. Magic Square 
5.Transpose
5

enter the oder of matrix A :2
3

Input the Elements of the Matrix :1
2
3
4
5
6

The Matrix you enter is :
1  2  3
4  5  6
the transpose of the entered matrix is :
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

And there is some problem in the multiplication function also, there also right matrix is not being displayed.

Comment: TL:DR : did you try using either `r` or `c` for both the cases, allocation and looping?

Comment: `b= (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (int*)malloc(c*sizeof(int));
    }`

Comment: When you ran this under your debugger, which line raised the segfault?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY still seg. fault after implementing what you told and i don't this there is any reason for doing what you told me

Comment: `b[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`  allocate only one element for column.

Comment: see, there is problem in the function inputmatrix(), when i'm inserting matrix in which the no of row is greater than that of the column then there is seg. fault... Please try to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b= (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
```

This allocates an array of `r` `int*` elements.

```
 for(i=0; i<c; i++)
```

This goes over the first `c` elements of this array. If `c>r`, then

```
 b[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

the behaviour of the line above is undefined. If `c<=r`, it is well-defined but not very useful, as it allocates one element for each matrix row. It probably becomes broken later, when you try to access elements past the first column.

To allocate a matrix with `r` rows and `c` columns you probably want to do this:

```
b = malloc(r * sizeof(int*));              /* allocate `r` rows */
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)                     /* for each of the `r` rows */
   b[i] = malloc (c * sizeof(int));        /* allocate `c` columns */
```